# CDVPlugin class CordovaStripe (pluginName: CordovaStripe) does not exist

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, stripe-payments

I am working with Ionic 3 and Stripe.

I am seeing this error on iOS Xcode debug.

> 2018-07-04 16:40:49.873337-0400 TestApp[2943:7783516] CDVPlugin class
>   CordovaStripe (pluginName: CordovaStripe) does not exist.
>
> 2018-07-04
>   16:40:49.873443-0400 TestApp[2943:7783516] ERROR: Plugin
>   'CordovaStripe' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin
>   mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2018-07-04 16:40:49.873527-0400
>   TestApp[2943:7783516] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142]
>   FAILED pluginJSON =
>   ["CordovaStripe1777748815","CordovaStripe","setPublishableKey",["pk_test_12345678900"]]

my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-stripe" spec="~1.5.3" />
```

> app.module.ts
>
> import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe';
>
> ...   providers: [ ...
>       Stripe   ] }) export class AppModule {}

```
> package.json    "dependencies": {   
>  "@ionic-native/stripe": "^4.9.0",
> 
>         "cordova-plugin-stripe": {}
>     },
>     "platforms": [
>         "android",
>         "ios"
>     ]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.. This was very strange.

- ionic cordova platform remove ios
- ionic cordova platform add ios
- npm install
- exit out of xcode
- restart and resign in xcode..

All seems to be working now..

Thanks
Phil